# Python библиотека для манипуляции телефоном

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, поиск-библиотек

Есть модуль по типу **pyautogui** но для телефонов?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит какая операционная система. Для таких задач есть несколько библиотек:

- [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) - изначально задумывался как расширение для monkeyrunner, но в последнее время превратился в чистый инструмент на Python, который автоматизирует или упрощает создание тестовых скриптов для android смарфонов;
- [Appium](https://github.com/appium/appium) - это кроссплатформенный инструмент автоматизации тестирования с открытым исходным кодом для нативных, гибридных и мобильных веб-приложений и настольных приложений. Мы поддерживаем симуляторы (iOS), эмуляторы (Android) и реальные устройства (iOS, Android, Windows, Mac).